# @login_required en clases basadas en vistas

Tags: django

Veran, tengo la siguiente vista:

```
class contenido_adicional(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form=bonus()
        return render(request,'privilegio.html',{'forma':form})
    def post(self,request):
        form=bonus(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tex=form.cleaned_data['texto']
            ani=form.cleaned_data['animal']
            documento=extra(texto=tex,animal=ani)
            documento.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return render(request,'privilegio.html',{'forma':form})
```

Quiero hacer que esa vista solo pueda acceder a ella un usuario con sesión abierta.
Se que si quiero en una vista tipo request que no entre un usuario sin sesión, puedo usar @login_required, pero esto no funciona en las vistas tipo view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que hacer que tu vista extienda a [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class contenido_adicional(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self,request):
        form=bonus()
        return render(request,'privilegio.html',{'forma':form})
    def post(self,request):
        form=bonus(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            tex=form.cleaned_data['texto']
            ani=form.cleaned_data['animal']
            documento=extra(texto=tex,animal=ani)
            documento.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return render(request,'privilegio.html',{'forma':form})
```

Comment: Pues gracias, ha funcionado.

Comment: De nada, @MiguelAlparez :).